# how to check whether this cycle happens or not?

Tags: oracle

I'm having a requirement guys.That i want to find whether this cycle occur or not. I don't know where to start with.
A table is having columns like this

```
Issue_no  old_value new value
   1         a        b
   1         b        c
   1         c        d
   1         d        a
```

I want to find whether after old value d it goes to a or not.The cycle has to be like this a to b,b to c, c to d.But i want to know whether d to a occurs or not.Can anyone know how to find that?

Comment: Can you explain little more on your problem? It seems you are looking for **Hierarchical Query** this can be done by using **CONNECT BY PRIOR**. Your table already looks like your requirement.

Comment: @ChiranjeeviSurapraju Like consider a life cycle,a process goes into the new state after that scheduled then execution then completed.These are the values present in old_value and new_value.I have to find the count that how many times the process went from completed to new state

Comment: Do the values always increase in sequence such that `ASCII( old_value ) + 1 = ASCII( new_value )` and only if there is a cycle will `old_value >= new_value`?

Answer (score 1):

This will look for cycles in your data:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82740/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Issue_no,  old_value, new_value ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'b', 'c' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'c', 'd' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'd', 'a' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'b', 'c' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'c', 'd' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'd', 'e' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'b', 'a' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1 - If you just want to list all the cycles**:

```
SELECT Issue_no,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT old_value || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( new_value, '-' ) AS cyclic_path
FROM   TEST t
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 1
START WITH
      old_value = 'a'
CONNECT BY
      NOCYCLE
      PRIOR issue_no  = issue_no
AND   PRIOR new_value = old_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82740/3/0)**:

```
| ISSUE_NO | CYCLIC_PATH |
|----------|-------------|
|        1 |   a-b-c-d-a |
|        3 |       a-b-a |
```

**Query 2 - If you want to find the particular cycle `a-b-c-d-a`**:

```
SELECT Issue_no
FROM (
  SELECT Issue_no,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT old_value || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( new_value, '-' ) AS cyclic_path
  FROM   TEST t
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE = 1
  START WITH
        old_value = 'a'
  CONNECT BY
        NOCYCLE
        PRIOR issue_no  = issue_no
  AND   PRIOR new_value = old_value
)
WHERE cyclic_path = 'a-b-c-d-a'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82740/3/1)**:

```
| ISSUE_NO |
|----------|
|        1 |
```

Comment: @MTO Can you help me with other thing.That's not the only cycle i have to find.But i also have to find for 6 possible traversing.Like this is my original cycle a->b->c->d->e,From d and e i have to check whether it went to a or b or c